# Texture color change on click mouse button as a brash in paint

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a material attached to the game object .

Material has a texture .

I have another  texture of different color .

what I want is that when I click on the game object .
Only the corresponding position's texture will change the color and it will be the color of the another texture that I have .

Actually I want to create a Tool like Eraser in paint .
Eraser erase or white only the position where I press mouse click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use RaycastHit.barycentricCoordinate.

record all erase uv positons,notify shader by a Texture.

shader earse color.

see [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord.html)